# Socialengine addon Advanced Events Plugin v4.8.8p2 throwing errror on create

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I've got a site set up with the base Socialengine setup going. I've installed most of the SocialEngineAddon suite of plugins, and for some reason, the Advanced Events plugin throws this error when I try and create one ie: example.com/appeals/create I've tried renaming back to the default site-event, but the problem persists, and I'm having trouble debugging this error. Has anyone seen an error like this before? (I'm quite new to Zend/SocialEngine)

```
exception 'Zend_Form_Exception' with message 'No view script registered with ViewScript decorator' in /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Form/Decorator/ViewScript.php:162
Stack trace:
#0 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Form/DisplayGroup.php(920): Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript->render('')
#1 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Form/Decorator/FormElements.php(116): Zend_Form_DisplayGroup->render()
#2 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Form.php(2933): Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements->render('')
#3 /home/activism/public_html/application/modules/Siteevent/views/scripts/index/create.tpl(294): Zend_Form->render(Object(Zend_View))
#4 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('/home/activism/...')
#5 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(890): Zend_View->_run('/home/activism/...')
#6 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(900): Zend_View_Abstract->render('index/create.tp...')
#7 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(921): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('index/create.tp...', NULL)
#8 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(960): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#9 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#10 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(527): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
#11 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('createAction')
#12 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#13 /home/activism/public_html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(83): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/activism/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#15 /home/activism/public_html/application/index.php(211): Engine_Application->run()
#16 /home/activism/public_html/index.php(24): include('/home/activism/...')
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you need to verify license .Contact the Socialengineaddson guys will help you.

Comment: Yeah - seems like that did the trick - appreciate your answer!